# Define json polygon's color by data from csv in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, csv, leaflet

I want to do something that i thought would be pretty easy but i face a problem.

I have two files : a geojson file with geometry and a csv with two columns, one for data and an another which shares attribute with a propertie in the geojson, a `name` to be simple.

I want to make a choropleth map depending of data from my csv to fill my geojson polygon. I check the [leaflet documentation for choropleth map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) with json and [i follow, in part, this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143730/leafletjs-combine-location-data-in-geojson-kml-gpx-with-other-information-in-c) for communication between json and csv in leaflet.

So, this is a part of my code which is problematic, json polygons are mapped but colors are not define. I learn JS so sorry for the mistakes :

**EDIT** : fix typo

```
Papa.parse("score.csv", {
    download: true,
    header: true,
    delimiter: "",
    complete: function(results) { //everything below runs only after the CSV has been loaded and processed.

        function getColor(d) {
            return d > 0.5 ? '#800026' :
                   d > 0.4  ? '#BD0026' :
                   d > 0.3  ? '#E31A1C' :
                   d > 0.25  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                   d > 0.2   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                   d > 0.15   ? '#FEB24C' :
                   d > 0.1   ? '#FED976' :
                              '#FFEDA0';
        }

        var oiseLayer = new L.geoJson(oise, {
                style: function(feature){
                    // var filtered = results.data.filter(function(data){return data.DCOMIRIS == this;}, feature.properties.DCOMIRIS.toString());

                    if (results.data.DCOMIRIS == feature.properties.DCOMIRIS){
                    return {
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        color: 'white',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        fillColor: getColor(results.data.score)
                    }
                }
                }
           }).addTo(map);
}
});
```

My json looks like this :

```
var oise = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DEPCOM": "60538", "NOM_COM": "Ricquebourg", "IRIS": "0000", "DCOMIRIS": "605380000", "NOM_IRIS": "Ricquebourg", "TYP_IRIS": "Z" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 2.753862487322691, 49.568106423004863 ], [ 2.754834569610532, 49.567467723103867 ], [ 2.755374727888817, 49.567112846570275 ], [ 2.75585282747064, 49.566527871018629 ], [ 2.755916398961054, 49.56594385787055 ], [ 2.755844137158009, 49.565449439131314 ], [ 2.755354284133803, 49.564733104021172 ], [ 2.756729896258653, 49.564817378618457 ], [ 2.758105512897535, 49.564901637620451 ],...
```

And my csv :

```
DCOMIRIS;score
600010000;0.025
600020000;0.03333333333333333
```

Besides, i got an error in my console which says that my csv transform in json is "not well-formed".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `if (result.data.DCOMIRIS == feature.properties.DCOMIRIS){` => should be `results` with **s** to match your function argument identifier.

But this is not the core of your issue.

`results.data` is an array of items (one per line in your CSV file, except for the first / header line). So the `if` condition "`result.data.DCOMIRIS == feature.properties.DCOMIRIS`" will never be met.

You should rather map your `DCOMIRIS` codes in an object, so that you can easily refer to these codes when parsing the GeoJSON data and trying to determine the appropriate style / color. See my answer in that other question: [Leaflet GeoJSON zoom to marker by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793979/leaflet-geojson-zoom-to-marker-by-id)

```
// map the DCOMIRIS first, so that we can retrieve them by DCOMIRIS easily.
var DCOMIRIS = {},
  data = results.data;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
  DCOMIRIS[data[i].DCOMIRIS] = data[i].score;
}
```

Then you can retrieve the `score` of your feature by calling `DCOMIRIS[feature.properties.DCOMIRIS]`

Then, I think PapaParse gives you only strings, so you will have to convert the `score` to a float: `parseFloat(score)`

Finally you can use your `getColor` function:

```
var oiseLayer = L.geoJson(oise, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      fillColor: getColor(parseFloat(DCOMIRIS[feature.properties.DCOMIRIS]))
    };
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/185/

NOTE: not sure about your `delimiter: ""`, that may explain your console error. Why not leaving the delimiter automatic detection?

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm ! for the `delimiter : ""` it was in the Papaparse documentation so i can't figure it out... I don't think it will be hard as this. I will fix typo in my question.